# Draw a part of bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a bitmap and 2 machines, if I want to send that bitmap from machine 1 to machine 2, I need to write to byte array. 
Problem is: for each time send data, my machine can only send 119 byte.

Each time I receive 119 bytes, I want to decode that bytes to bitmap and set to ImageView, how can I do that?

Like this picture

[image]

Comment: i haven't code any thing in android yet, i just want to know how to draw a bitmap from byte array, for example :
i have byte array which was write from a bitmap: source = [119, 0, 0 23 , ...]
and i want to draw apart (119 byte) of that byte array to bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Use BitmapFactory's decodeByteArray: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Comment: if i decode all of byte array it's ok, but a part a byte array (119 byte), it's not